# why i am getting "ValueError: math domain error" exception in my code?

Tags: python

this is my first time posting here so I'm sorry if I mess anything up or format incorrectly. In an attempt to bring a lot of the very basic stuff I've learned together in Python, I'm trying to make a quadratic equation calculator where you can type in each of your 3 values and be given the horizontal intercepts. However, while this works with some problems, others will give me this message:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "quadeq.py", line 18, in <module>
result1 = ((float(ac)) + (sqrt((float(ab)) - (float(aa))))) / (float(ad))

ValueError: math domain error"
```

I'm pretty sure this is just an error with my math, but it could be a lot of other things too. Thanks much to anyone willing to check this out, it would be much appreciated.

```
from math import *

print("Please enter each of your values!")
a = input("Enter a value: ")
b = input("Enter b value: ")
c = input("Enter c value: ")
d = -4

aa = float(d) * ((float(a)) * (float(c)))
ab = ((float(b))) * ((float(b)))
ac = 0 - (float(b))
ad = (2) * (float(a))

result1 = ((float(ac)) + (sqrt((float(ab)) - (float(aa))))) / (float(ad))
result2 = ((float(ac)) - (sqrt((float(ab)) - (float(aa))))) / (float(ad))

print("Your values are: " + str(result1) + " and " + str(result2))
```

Comment: `math.sqrt` doesn't work with negative numbers. So you need to check for the case where `ab < aa`.

Comment: d should be +4, since you are using minus in result1 and result2

Answer (score 1):

you have some corner cases that you need to take in mind:

1. `ZeroDivisionError` : since your code includes divisions, you need to cover this.
2. `ValueError` : `math.sqrt` cant accept negative numbers! in such case this will raise `ValueError: math domain error`

you can use try except to handle these corner case.now you can do it in the operations step (no nned to check inputs with `if-else` like old days. this is non pythonic!) see below:

```
import math

print("Please enter each of your values!")
a = input("Enter a value: ")
b = input("Enter b value: ")
c = input("Enter c value: ")
d = -4

aa = float(d) * ((float(a)) * (float(c)))
ab = ((float(b))) * ((float(b)))
ac = 0 - (float(b))
ad = (2) * (float(a))

try:
    result1 = ((float(ac)) + (sqrt((float(ab)) - (float(aa))))) / (float(ad))
    result2 = ((float(ac)) - (sqrt((float(ab)) - (float(aa))))) / (float(ad))
    print("Your values are: " + str(result1) + " and " + str(result2))
except(ZeroDivisionError, ValueError):
    #do some work here, e.g tell the user something
    print("....")
```

Answer (score 0):

you have already accounted for subtraction when you substituted `d = -4`

change this `sqrt((float(ab)) - (float(aa))))` to `sqrt((float(ab)) + (float(aa))))`

also, you should consider using the try-except block because the quadratic equation might have imaginary roots.

---

on a side note, your code contains a lot of redundant parentheses ;)